# Creating a Shinydashboard style menu in navbarPage under a tabpanel?

Tags: r, shiny, navbar, shinydashboard

Working on a `Shiny` dashboard which has the structure `navbarPage/navbarMenu/tabPanel/sidebarLayout`. For one panel I would like to create a Shinydashboard style menu like the picture below with some different `inputs` under each item. Is this possible?

[image]

Start of my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage("Shiny Tool",
  
  navbarMenu("Section 1",
             tabPanel("Section 1.1",
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard"),
                        menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets")
                      )
             ),
             mainPanel()
                      
                      
                      )
             )))
  

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This should be possible. Could you clarify about the expected output? Is your goal to have one `tabPanel` which has a `dashboardSidebar` menu as shown in the picture (wrap it inside the `tabPanel`?)? What do you mean by different `inputs`?

Comment: @Jan I mean inputs like datePicker, textInput etc. My goal is to have multiple tabPanels, which have dashboardSidebar